# How can I decode a token sent to a user to know when it was created

Tags: django, sha

Hello I did a reset password system in my web that sends a token link to the client's mail in order to client can reset the password, And I want to check the timestap of the hashed token, to make some condition like... expire in 24h.

This file makes the token and I "guess" is hashing user.pk and timestap and returning a hashed token. I want to make reverse process to know when that token was created.

tokens.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
import six

class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp)
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Token link is going perfect and client can change the passord whitn no problems.
this is my view that handle this with 2 functions 1st for sending the mail, and 2nd for reset the password.

views.py:

```
def reset_password(request):
    form = ResetPasswordForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        if not user:
            messages.error(request,'This user does not exist')
        else:
            user = user.first()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Reset Password'
            message = render_to_string('core/reset_password_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })

            send_mail(subject,message,conf_settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[user.email,])
            messages.success(request,'Password reset link sent to your email')
            return redirect('consumer:consumer_home')

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,'core/password_reset.html',context)

def reset_password_confirm(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        form = ResetPasswordConfirmationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,'Password changed!')
            return redirect('consumer:consumer_home')
            
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }    

    return render(request,'core/password_reset_confirmation.html',context)
```

Now I have no clue to how to decode client token in order to extract the timestap that I hashed when I sent it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you can update your `AccountActivationTokenGenerator` to include a timestamp:

```
class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
    return (
        six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) + six.text_type(time.time())
    )
```

You can then create a function to check the token when confirming the reset:

```
def reset_password_confirm(request, uidb64, token):
    def check_token(token):
        try:
            user_id, timestamp, creation_time = token.split(":")
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            if account_activation_token._make_hash_value(user, timestamp) != token:
                return False
            return user, creation_time
        except Exception:
            return False

    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    result = check_token(token)
    if user is not None and result:
        user, creation_time = result
        form = ResetPasswordConfirmationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Password changed!")
            return redirect("consumer:consumer_home")

    context = {'form':form,}


return render(request, "core/password_reset_confirmation.html", context)
```

You'll then have access to `creation_time` which you can use in template through context.